# flask sqlalchemy bind causing could not assemple primary key error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Problem** I have a flask app in which my sqlalchemy reflect() works differently for binds specified by SQLALCHEMY_BINDS than for SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI.

**Result** SQLALCHEMY_BINDS will not auto map my schema.

I have two databases as shown in my config.py

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://chet@localhost/ubuntuweb'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'test':        'postgresql://chet@localhost/warehouse',
 }
```

which ever db i put in the URI db is streamlined, and works by using reflect() without any issues

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

class rutable(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['rutable']
```

When i add this code in my models.py

```
class test1(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'test'
    __table__ =  db.Model.metadata.tables['test1']

results in this error

    __table__ =  db.Model.metadata.tables['test1']
   KeyError: 'test1'
```

however this works

```
class test1(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'test'
    __tablename__ = 'test1'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    test = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

it works great.  this is the full mapping of the schema.  I want to take advantage of not needing to manually write out he variables. when I reduce it to

```
class test1(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'test'
```

stack trace

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class 'app.models.test1'> 
does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not 
inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

when i add the tablename

```
class test1(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'test'
    __tablename__ = 'test1'

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|test1|test 
could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'test1'
```

Any idea why this is happening?
when i investigate the id column in my table, it looks like a primary key in psql

thanks!

Comment: Did you found out how to do this ?